# Django-cas - 403 error after successful logging in

Tags: python, django, cas

I'm trying to include CAS authentication in my website. I installed https://github.com/KTHse/django-cas2 and configured MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES, AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS and CAS_SERVER_URL (as in README.md). I also setup own CAS server on localhost. In my urls.py I have:

```
...
url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django_cas.views.login'),
url(r'^accounts/logout/$', 'django_cas.views.logout'),
...
```

When I'm visiting accounts/login/ it redirects me to CAS server site. But after successful log in, CAS server site redirects me back to accounts/login/?next=%2F&ticket=ticket_here and this URL gives me 403 error, none cookies are setted. What I should do to get it working?

PS. In cmd I get error: `No handlers could be found for logger "django_cas.backends"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to set `CAS_AUTO_CREATE_USERS` to `True`, add `'django_cas'` to `INSTALLED_APPS` and finally sync database.

Comment: What if I don't want CAS to auto create user?